# Navigating along rapid.xml nodes

Tags: rapidxml

This question slightly differs from [check for variable number of sibling nodes & different siblings in Rapidxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783171/). In most of the examples I have found on the web I see hard coded keys, for example:

```
xml_node<>* root = doc.first_node("rootnode");
```

Here "rootnode" is hard coded. My situation is slightly different, in the sense that parsing and tagging is already done by rapidxml. I need to know the names as read by the parser by iterating over nodes and their sibling without knowing the hard coded name and the depth of the node. I am looking for the suggestion/solution on some kind of recursive navigation along rapidxml tree.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to RapidXml's documentation ([see here](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#classrapidxml_1_1xml__node_7823e36687669e59c2afdf66334ef35a_17823e36687669e59c2afdf66334ef35a)) the node name parameter in `first_node()` method is optional. You can just omit that parameter and you will get the first child node, regardless of its name:

```
xml_node<>* root = doc.first_node();
```

Then you can just get node's name by calling its `name()` method.